# How to run SQLite3 database (in WAL mode) in Flask

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlite

SQLite3 database connection, when created in WAL mode (as shown below) allows multiple threads to read data through a single connection. This mode greatly enhances the read scalability of any web application.

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect('mydb.sqlite3')
db.execute('pragma journal_mode=wal')
```

For details please refer to [Going Fast with SQLite and Python](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/going-fast-with-sqlite-and-python/)

I'm working on a web application in Flask where SQLite3 is used for persistance as there are very few users who will be making update to database. However there will be far many users who will be reading the contents. So i think database in WAL mode will greatly enhance the read performance of this application.

As per [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/), the SQLite3 database connection is opened/closed for every request. This approach seems fine for connections that make update to database (i.e. writers). But for selects (i.e. readers), this approach of opening and closing connection for each request seems to be limiting.

Can somebody guide me on how to run a shared SQLite3 database in WAL mode (for selects only)  in Flask? (version 0.12.2 on python 3)

Comment: [WAL mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html) makes a difference only if there is a writer. And WAL mode is a property of the database file, not of the connection.

Comment: Yes I intend to make two separate connections, (1) writer connection for making updates and (2) reader connections for serving selects.